# What is the difference between localname and qname?

Tags: java, xml, sax

When using SAX to parse an XML file in Java, what is the difference between the parameters **localname** and **qname** in SAX methods such as `startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes attributes)`?

Answer (score 45):

The qualified name includes both the namespace prefix and the local name: `att1` and `foo:att2`.

**Sample XML**

```
<root 
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/DEFAULT" 
    att1="Hello" 
    xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com/FOO" 
    foo:att2="World"/>
```

**Java Code:**

***att1***

Attributes without a namespace prefix do not pick up the default namespace.  This means while the namespace for the `root` element is `"http://www.example.com/DEFAULT"`, the namespace for the `att1` attribute is `""`.

```
int att1Index = attributes.getIndex("", "att1");
attributes.getLocalName(att1Index);  // returns "att1"
attributes.getQName(att1Index);  // returns "att1"
attributes.getURI(att1Index);  // returns ""
```

***att2***

```
int att2Index = attributes.getIndex("http://www.example.com/FOO", "att2");
attributes.getLocalName(att2Index);  // returns "att2"
attributes.getQName(att2Index);  // returns "foo:att2"
attributes.getURI(att2Index);  // returns "http://www.example.com/FOO"
```

Answer (score 13):

Generally speaking, localname is the local name, meaning inside the namespace. qname, or qualified name, is the full name (including namespace). For example, <a:b …> will have a localname b, but a qname a:b.

This is however very general, and settings-dependant. Take a look at the example at the end of this page for a more thorough example: [example](http://www.saxproject.org/namespaces.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default, an XML reader will report a Namespace URI and a localName for every element that belongs in a namespace, in both the start and end handler.

Consider the following example:

```
  <html:hr xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
```

With the default SAX2 Namespace processing, the XML reader would report a start and end element event with the Namespace URI http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml and the localName hr. Most XMLReader implementations also report the original qName html:hr, but that parameter might simply be an empty string (except for elements that aren't in a namespace).

http://www.saxproject.org/namespaces.html

Comment: Question: will the qName be the prefix + ':' + the local name, or will it be '{' + namespace URI + '}' + local name? Like so: `{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}hr`. Because a prefix binds an element to a namespace, but its actual string should be of no importance. Qualified = namespace and local name.

Comment: It will be `prefix+":"+localname`. (But you can find that out by looking in the Javadoc, or in the output of a parser - why do you ask here?)