# what does the arguments of startelement() method in SAX parser refer to

Tags: saxparser

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes)
```

can anybody please give a simple example as to how localname is different from qName and what exactly is the uri string ? And yes before somebody asks I did check it on the net but no one cared to mention the difference as some examples used qName and others used localname which is really confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i found the answer here http://www.saxproject.org/namespaces.html

and here [What is the difference between localname and qname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157355/what-is-the-difference-between-localname-and-qname)